# List data sorted by count of specific value

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get orders from a shop database ordered by the count of occurences of the countries. This is the query I have by now:

```
select /*o.id                                        as id,*/
    concat_ws(" ", oa.first_name, oa.last_name) as name,
    oa.street                                   as street,
    oa.city                                     as city,
    oa.additional_address_line1                 as additionaladdressline1,
    oa.additional_address_line2                 as additionaladdressline2,
    ct.name                                     as country,
    oa.zipcode                                  as zipcode,
    o.order_number                              as ordernumber,
    o.customer_comment                          as comment,
    /*o.sales_channel_id                          as saleschannel,*/
    oc.email                                    as email
from order_address oa
         join `order` o on o.id = oa.order_id
         join state_machine_state orderstate on o.state_id = orderstate.id and orderstate.technical_name = 'open'
         join order_customer oc on o.id = oc.order_id
         join order_transaction ot on o.id = ot.order_id
         join order_delivery od on o.id = od.order_id and oa.id = od.shipping_order_address_id
         join country c on oa.country_id = c.id
         join country_translation ct on c.id = ct.country_id
         join language l on ct.language_id = l.id
         join state_machine_state paymentstate
              on ot.state_id = paymentstate.id and paymentstate.technical_name = 'paid'
         join order_line_item oli on o.id = oli.order_id and o.version_id = oli.order_version_id
         join state_machine_state deliverystate on deliverystate.id = od.state_id
where o.order_number not in (
    select distinct o.order_number as ordernumber
    from `order` o
             join state_machine_state orderstate
                  on o.state_id = orderstate.id and orderstate.technical_name <> 'open')
  and l.name = 'Deutsch'
group by o.order_number
order by c.id, count(distinct oli.identifier) desc, sum(oli.quantity) desc
```

This is the result I get from the query:

```
+--------------------+------------------+-------------------+------------------------+------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+------------+-------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------+
| name               | street           | city              | additionaladdressline1 | additionaladdressline2 | country                                           | zipcode    | ordernumber | comment | email                                                      |
+--------------------+------------------+-------------------+------------------------+------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+------------+-------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------+
| Nash Langosh       | Emmerich Neck    | New Korbin        | NULL                   | NULL                   | Turks- und Caicosinseln                           | 11706-2163 | 10034       | NULL    | c682bd0ff4c84988974f9435842b1fcbfriedrich61@example.org    |
| Trisha Sporer      | Hauck Neck       | Cormierchester    | NULL                   | NULL                   | Bahamas                                           | 21065-9255 | 10016       | NULL    | 702435261d53477995d6c64c3811ec58clinton.green@example.org  |
| Shana Satterfield  | Kallie Creek     | Wuckertstad       | NULL                   | NULL                   | Uganda                                            | 14142      | 10049       | NULL    | 1c390f2beee84ca8abc99f6adf79340bdiana.von@example.net      |
| Nicolette Dibbert  | Emma Burg        | Maymieton         | NULL                   | NULL                   | Uganda                                            | 15379      | 10054       | NULL    | 80a5fdca130448fe94549095ba19492fbruen.kaylee@example.net   |
| Ethelyn Runolfsson | Toy Tunnel       | Hicklefurt        | NULL                   | NULL                   | Finnland                                          | 01540-1774 | 10045       | NULL    | 84c0b38e32bf49d69220e8358bab94e2marks.dillan@example.com   |
| Euna Spencer       | Katarina Cove    | New Karinaland    | NULL                   | NULL                   | Finnland                                          | 14855      | 10009       | NULL    | bd216fe010064ccda556fd43eb52b3a4hessel.aubree@example.com  |
| Ethelyn Runolfsson | Toy Tunnel       | Hicklefurt        | NULL                   | NULL                   | Finnland                                          | 01540-1774 | 10029       | NULL    | 84c0b38e32bf49d69220e8358bab94e2marks.dillan@example.com   |
| Jamey Schamberger  | Larkin Mission   | Kobeport          | NULL                   | NULL                   | Svalbard und Jan Mayen                            | 27310-0364 | 10053       | NULL    | 50379c7b57f94639896d93fc1c563a7cbshanahan@example.net      |
| Moshe Lebsack      | Lakin Stream     | Purdystad         | NULL                   | NULL                   | Åland                                             | 67019      | 10012       | NULL    | 8fae2ae4bd0248f09c54e034c3f92eadleo89@example.com          |
| Kallie Murazik     | Kilback Junction | Tommieside        | NULL                   | NULL                   | Kleinere Inselbesitzungen der Vereinigten Staaten | 76849-7266 | 10028       | NULL    | f6ad7ba712ca463d9caed875587e421ageffertz@example.com       |
| Hank Hayes         | Kshlerin Ramp    | South Weldonshire | NULL                   | NULL                   | Gambia                                            | 06653      | 10008       | NULL    | 8537e6c081e8487ea4983a13045c6aedkelli.douglas@example.com  |
| Kallie Schmitt     | Mellie Mountains | New Blaketon      | NULL                   | NULL                   | Ecuador                                           | 41722-3737 | 10001       | NULL    | 47603affbbdd4a0b80d3233d4d41a716bsatterfield@example.org   |
| Carolyn Miller     | Therese Coves    | Venaview          | NULL                   | NULL                   | Kiribati                                          | 13115-5720 | 10006       | NULL    | 26179bb6125e4edf98e3f22225cf738fbayer.valentin@example.org |
+--------------------+------------------+-------------------+------------------------+------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+------------+-------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

How can I sort the orders by the count of occurences of the countries?

Comment: I didn't get , What it means by `frequency of countries` ? Do you mean the number of times the country present in the result set ? If yes then what happens with the same frequency ?

Comment: I meant by count of occurences, will change the question :)

Comment: If it is the same frequency, it doesn't really matter how it is sorted.

Comment: Your query is invalid by the way. You must not group by order number and still access the address, because there can be multiple addresses per order (hence the separate order_address table). As MySQL let's this slip, you can expect unexpected results. I suggest you set ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode, as long as you have problems with aggregation queries.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner thanks to mention that, I made a mistake in the join clause, there is a one-to-one relationship between `order`, `order_delivery` and `order_address`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to count the countries in your result and order the rows according to their frequency. Use `COUNT OVER` for this. In MySQL this is available as of version 8.

```
order by count(*) over (partition by c.id) desc, c.id
```